# How to pass an anonymous sub to Find::File

Tags: perl, perl-module

I know I can do this as an expression modifier:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use File::Find;

sub file_find{
    my ($path,$filter) = @_;
    find(sub {print $File::Find::name."\n" if /$filter/}, $path);   
}
file_find($newdir,'\.txt');
```

or this which is less readable:

```
find(sub {if(/$filter/){print $File::Find::name."\n"}}, $path);
```

But if I wanted to do something like this, how can I do it?

```
sub file_find{
    my ($path,$filter) = @_;

    find(\&print, $path);

    sub print {
        if(/$filter/){ #Variable $filter will not stay shared
            print $File::Find::name."\n";
        }
    }   
}
file_find($newdir,'\.txt')
```

I get 'variable will not stay shared'. I believe I'm supposed to make it an anonymous sub:

```
my $print = sub {
    if(/$filter/){
        print $File::Find::name."\n";
    }
}
```

But then I don't know how to pass the reference to the find sub. Perhaps it's somthing silly I'm missing.

Edit: Never mind, this seems to work:

```
sub file_find{
    my ($path,$filter) = @_;    

    my $subref = sub{
        if(/$filter/){
            print $File::Find::name."\n";
        }
    };

    find($subref,$path);    

}
file_find($newdir,'\.txt');
```

I had to push the find sub to the bottom! Man I feel so dumb :)

Comment: You tried putting a named sub definition inside another sub. Maybe you intended that sub to be lexical (that means it's only valid inside that other sub, like a variable declared with `my`), or maybe you just didn't pay attention. But it's not correct anyway. The problem is with how Perl parses those sub definitions at compile time, and the variables are available at run time. Your solution with the code reference in a lexical variable is way better.

Answer (score 2):

I would separate the subs apart (and rename the `print()` one as it conflicts with the built-in with the same name!), then you can do something along these lines (if I'm understanding what you want correctly):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find;

file_find('.', '.txt');

sub file_find{
    my ($path,$filter) = @_;
    my @files = find(sub {my_print($filter)}, $path);
}
sub my_print {
    my $filter = shift;

    my $fname = $File::Find::name;

    if($fname =~ /$filter/){
        print "$fname\n";
    }
}
```

However, with that said, [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) can make these things very, very easy (particularly handling the file filters as it handles regex natively):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find::Rule;

my $filter = '*.txt';
my $dir = '.';

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->name($filter)
                            ->in($dir);

print "$_\n" for @files;
```